# How can I fetch this info in laravel Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

Sorry for the question title but I can't really find an suitible title.

I use Laravel 3 with Eloquent models (first project in Laravel). 
I have an `user`, `list` and `item` model. The user can't fetch any lists, the list can fetch items. But the user can order the items, so the order is saved per user/item.

Will be more clear with following data (simplified for clarity):

Database table:

```
USER
--------
id
name

LIST
-------
id
name

ITEM
-------
id
list_id
name

USER_ITEM_ORDER
---------------
user_id
item_id
order
```

List model:

```
class List extends Eloquent {
    public function items() {
        return $this->has_many('Item');
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the list model to get all the items based on an user, `$list->items($user_id)` --> array with items with the user's order.

Can someone show me the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! I fixed it. :D I'll answer my own question because there is an up vote..

It was pretty easy, just use [Fluent](http://acms.acms-test.local/docs/database/fluent) on the returned object like this:

```
public function items($user_id = 0) {
    $items = $this->has_many('Item');

    // do we need to get the order?
    if($user_id != 0) {
        $items = $items->left_join('user_item_order', 'items.id', '=', 'user_item_order.item_id')
                       ->where('user_item_order.user_id', '=', $user_id)
                       ->order_by('user_item_order.order', 'asc');
    }

    return $items->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this code :

```
public static function NAMEUserId() {
        $query = DB::table('username')
        ->select(array('users.username', DB::raw('NAME(user's.id) as UserID')))
        ->join('users', 'items.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->group_by('users.id')
        ->order_by('usersid', 'desc')
        ->get();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I don't want to count the total items an user added, I want to fetch all the items and that the items has the user's order property set.

Comment: Means you want to keep order details by user's name?

Comment: I think yes.. But to be sure; Every user can order the same list items. The system saves the order per user. I want to receive the items with the user's order.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I found the solution, see my answer :)

Comment: That's great. How you did that ?